# is it possible to hide Bottom navigation bar in android but not notification bar in android

Tags: android

I am trying to hide bottom bar in rooted android tablet by using below code. But the upper notification bar is also hide with bottom bar, but I do not want to hide upper notification bar. 
 Is it possible to hide bottom navigation bar only?

```
public static void hideSystemBottomBar() {
        Process proc = null;

        String ProcID = "79"; // HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            ProcID = "42"; // ICS AND NEWER
        }

        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    new String[] {
                            "su",
                            "-c",
                            "service call activity " + ProcID
                                    + " s16 com.android.systemui" });


            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for,

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

NOTE: it should be above **setContentView**(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: No sir...i want to make it full screen activity which do not have bottom navigation bar but it should have upper notification bar.